# Firebase ListenerForSingleValueEvent not firing onCreate but is onResume()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i have a MainActivity that should bring up a set of data from Firebase when it's onCreate method is run however, the List is returning 0 each time.

Notably when i go to another activity (pause MainActivity) and then onResume() is called when going back to MainActivity the method runs fine returning the required results.....i suspect this is sometihng to do with the activity life cycle but can't seem to pin it down.

Placing the method in both onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() has the same result of 0 and the same behaviour in terms of navigating to another activity and coming back gives me the data.

Any thoughts?

My onResume() method:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_EXTERNAL);
        }

        try{
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                double lattitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("GeoFire");
                GeoFire geofire = new GeoFire(ref);
                geofire.setLocation(auth.getUid(), new GeoLocation(lattitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        if (error != null) {
                            System.err.println("There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Location saved on server successfully!");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });}
        catch (SecurityException e){

        }
        generateData();
        }
```

mFusedLocationClient is a instance of the class FusedLocationProvierClient. Documentation can be found [here.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient)

GenerateData Method:

```
 userDb.orderByChild("aField").equalTo(constraint).limitToLast(50).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   getUserList(); // runs geolocation

                    //GENERATE LIST
                   for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       try {

                           User tempUser = ds.getValue(User.class);
                            userList.add(tempUser);
                            setActive(userList);
                           }
                           Log.d("userListSize", String.valueOf(userList.size()));

                       } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                           Log.d("Index EXception", e.getMessage());
                       }
                   }
               }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                   }
               });
```

Comment: What doesn't work about this code? Note that we have no way of knowing what `mFusedLocationClient` and `generateData()` are, so you might want to look into [how to create a minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i don't think it's necessarily a problem with generateData() or the FusedLocationClient because they're all being executed fine when onResume() is called coming back to the MainActivity so i don't think the problem is with those areas.

Comment: @JamesPalfrey What is the problem with this code? Please also add what Frank van Puffelen has asked for, the code for `mFusedLocationClient` and `generateData()`.

Comment: I don't quite know the problem i'm having is that it is meant to load data into an Array to be displayed for the user. when the app first starts it doesn't display this, however if i navigate away from the page (pause MainActivity) and navigate back...the code works perfectly.